# program crashing while assigning a new node to tree node

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, dereference

I have written a c program for tree.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
 };

 struct node* newNode(int value){
    struct node* temp;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->data = value;

    return temp;
 }

 int main(){
    struct node *root;
    root = newNode(60);
    root->left = newNode(40);
    root->right = newNode(80);
    root->left->left = newNode(30); // program crashes here. 
    root->left->right = newNode(50);

 }
```

This is a sub-part of another program that I am writing. while debugging I realized that I am getting an error at assigning `newNode(30)`. I can't understand why ?

Comment: `struct node* temp;` --> `struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `newNode()` function, you are doing

```
struct node* temp;
temp->left = NULL;     //invalid memory access
temp->right = NULL;    //invalid memory access
temp->data = value;    //invalid memory access
```

but, `temp` is not allocated any valid memory. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when you dereference an invalid pointer.

You need to allocate memory to `temp` before you can dereference `temp`. You can make use of `malloc()` and family to get this done, something like,

```
struct node* temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);
if (temp )
{
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->data = value;
}
```

should get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory for the new node. Like

```
struct node* temp;
temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

And when your done you must remember to `free` the memory again.